# Testing shutil.move()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Wondering what would be a reasonable way to test Python's `shutil.move()` on a file that would already be opened. Would it make sense to just open a file with writing actions, and then try to run `shutil.move()` on it?

I have simply:

```
with open ('myfile.txt', 'w') as filename:
    shutil.move(r'/curr/dir/myfile.txt', r'/new/dir/myfile.txt')
```

Comment: why would you like to do that?

Comment: Well what do you want to figure out?

Comment: This would get better answers on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).  The only thing that comes to my mind is, you might want to do the `move` in a different process than the one that has the file open.

Comment: Behavior is operating system dependent. Following `zwio` 's advice to test with multiple processes, it should work on linux but I think it fails on windows.